# How to identify ethereum nft holders on polygon?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, ethereumjs, polygon

I have an nft contract 'A' deployed on ethereum and I want to have a contract deployed on polygon to identify which users are the nft holders of 'A'.

In short I want to identity the nft holders of 'A' on chain using a polygon contract/ anything. ( but must be onchain process)

How may I do that?

Edited- I have heard there is a thing called sub-graph that can fetch data.
Not sure what that is